# How to run protractor in components

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor

I know protractor is used as a testing framework. I am using Angular 2 for my application. I would like to use it in my app components like opening a browser when pressing a button. What should be the configuration for protractor.conf.js and tsconfig.json for it? Please let me know.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to ask. Protractor is for running end to end tests for the whole application, not individual component unit tests. For that, use something like Jasmine, and read the guidance in the documentation: https://angular.io/guide/testing. If you're unsure how to set up a project, consider using the Angular CLI, which sets up both Protractor and Jasmine tests.

Answer (score -1):

Please follow the official Protractor documentation for the same. The official Github has a link dedicated to the `.ts` examples. Here is the [link](https://github.com/angular/protractor/tree/5.3.2/exampleTypescript) for the same. Both `conf.ts` and `tsconfig.json` samples are provided here.

You can also follow these links - [link1](http://qavalidation.com/2017/06/protractor-setup-jasmine-typescript-vscode.html/), [link2](http://www.webdriverjs.com/protractor-example-with-typescript/) for the same